# Is this statement right? Ferrari just released a

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect, past-simple

I was reading this news over internet and i am wondering if this statement can be written differently or not.

> Ferrari just released a few photos of its upcoming limited-edition track-focused 812

Can "Ferrari just released a few photos" be also written as "Ferrari has released a few photos"?

if yes what difference it would make and how?

Answer (score 1):

'Ferrari has just released' and 'Ferrari just released' mean the same.

'Ferrari has just released'- British English

'Ferrari just released'- American English

In British English the present perfect tense is used with **just**, **already** and **yet**.

In American English either the present perfect tense or the simple past tense can be used with **just**, **already** and **yet**.

Comment: It's not quite so strict.  There is a tendency for brits to use perfect and yanks to use past in this situation, but it's not an absolute rule.

Comment: @James K
The present perfect is less common in American English than in British English. The American English speakers tend to use the simple past. But in British English the simple past is never used with just, already and yet.

Comment: It sometimes is used by native speakers of British English.

Comment: @James K  Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes, it is used in standard british english, but perhaps less often. than perfect.

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

*just released* could mean anything from released *seconds, minutes, hours, or perhaps even days* back. More context might clarify the exact proximity in time.

The present perfect version *has released* says likewise: that Ferrari released the photos in the past (maybe hours back or days back or perhaps even years back.) As in the previous case, more context is needed to know exactly when Ferrari released those photos.

Comment: Thanks, i am also wondering, why did the author chose "just released" instead of "has released" is there any other things which made the author to choose "just released".

Comment: He's probably American. As a British English speaker, I would have said _has just released. Just_ implies that the release was very recent.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you so much, I was just about to ask "Why hasn't he used 'has just released?' ". You explained it very well. many thanks :)